# Setup Cron to pkill -f

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have a script that runs in a loop. I can manually start the script from the command line easily enough with ./run_my_script but occasionally the script locks up and just needs a restart. So I ctrl-c and restart.
Now I want to create a cron to just periodically stop and restart the script. So in my cron I put:

```
00 * * * * pkill -f ./run_my_script && /bin/sleep 15 && ./run_my_script
```

This doesn't work. It kills the script but doesn't restart it so I try:

```
00 * * * * pkill -f ./run_my_script
00 * * * * /bin/sleep 15 && ./run_my_script
```

This doesn't work either. It kills the script, but doesn't restart it.
So I try:

```
00 * * * * pkill -f ./run_my_script
01 * * * * /bin/sleep 15 && ./run_my_script
```

And it works just fine. Problem is, I just need a few seconds between the kill and the restart, not a whole minute.
How can I do it?

Comment: If you add pkill and sleep command in the script?

Comment: Have you tried making a script that you call from cron instead of placing all the commands in cron? Unless I'm mistaken, cron runs something like `sh -c "{commands}"`, so `pkill -f` matches your command sequence and kills it before it has a chance to start your service.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, there is a [more elegant (?) approach.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-a-simple-bash-script-to-restart-server-programs)

Comment: Instead of `pkill`, which always has a risk of killing something else that accidentially has the same name, I'd rather use something like `timeout 3590 ./run_my_script` in a once-per-hour cron job so it stops just 10 seconds short of getting restarted.

Comment: 00 * * * * timeout 3590 is a slick one-liner that works! I like it...

Answer (score 5):

`pkill` only exits with a status of zero when "One or more processes matched the criteria". This means if `./run_my_script` isn't already running, the first `&&` in

```
pkill -f ./run_my_script && /bin/sleep 15 && ./run_my_script
```

will cause the rest not to run.

Using a semicolon rather than an and should work

```
pkill -f ./run_my_script ; /bin/sleep 15 && ./run_my_script
```

Comment: I'll try the semi-colon...

Comment: I was not able to get the semi-colon to work, I even changed sleep to to 45. I don't know why it didn't work. It worked off the console command line, just not in cron on the same line.... I have my crontab set to run some commands as well and have it setup as SHELL=/bin/bash So maybe that influences it?

Comment: Does it work if you encase the commands with `sh`? Like so: `sh -c "pkill -f ./run_my_script ; /bin/sleep 15 && ./run_my_script"`. I would also be wary of making statements relative to the current working directory, you may want to specify absolute paths.

Answer (score 2):

So I tried this and it is working:

```
00 * * * * /bin/sleep 45 && pkill -f ./run_my_script
01 * * * * ./run_my_script
```